# Implemenation of CIS Benchmark rule in Linux Hardening, we have issue in one of the rule which is "Ensure firewalld default zone is set (Automated)"

Tags: linux, ansible

• We are working on Linux OS hardening as per CIS Benchmark rules.
• We are using this command prompt to verify our rule which is "Ensure firewalld default zone is set (Automated)" :

Input Command :

**firewall-cmd --get-default-zone**

Output Command:

**firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=public
Firewall is set to be public**

- We have configured controller machine with the help of ansible and trying to fetch values in command prompt.
- But in command prompt we are unable to fetch output as "Firewall is set to be public" with our ansible script.

Can you please help us ansible script writing part where we get our desired output ?

Comment: Why you do not start to read about these "CIS Benchmark rules"? Of hire some consultant to implement them?

Comment: Please expand this question with a demonstration of what you tried, what you were hoping to get, and what you got instead. As it currently stands it's not a useful question or one that can be answered well.

Answer (score 1):

from existing syntax here I get the immediate impression there is misinterpretation and/or misuse of English.

> "Ensure firewalld default zone is set (Automated)"

post a link or the actual wording of the CIS rule....

`firewalld` is the standard linux firewall; it is already *automated* in that all network interfaces are assigned to the *default* zone, and the default zone is initially *public*.  If you don't like the `public` zone configuration you can either edit it, or create a new zone and then make your new zone the default zone which is in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` `DefaultZone=public` which refers to `/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml`.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-working_with_zones

> 5.7.3. Changing the Default Zone
>
> System administrators assign a zone to a networking interface in its configuration files. If an interface is not assigned to a specific zone, it is assigned to the default zone. After each restart of the firewalld service, firewalld loads the settings for the default zone and makes it active.

Comment: the other problem is 99% of the people involved will talk about *Linux Hardening* but have no idea wtf they are actually doing to *harden*.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a misunderstanding or a formatting error in the CIS benchmark document.

`Firewall is set to be public` is not actually the output of the `firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=public` command, but a description of the expected effect of that command.

If your Ansible script runs the command `firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=public` and the command exits without any errors, then the firewall default zone is successfully set to `public`.

To confirm this, your script can run the command `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone` and verify that it returns `public`.